# macOS High Sierra and CAShapeLayers, NSImageView, NSTableView confilcts

Tags: macos, cashapelayer, nsimageview, macos-high-sierra

I have updated to macOS High Sierra and have now unexpected problems in my project, the problems not seen before in macOS Sierra.
I have custom NSImageView and after drag and drop of image in this `NSImageView` I can draw the rectangles on top of the image using `CAShapeLayers` and `mouseDown`, `mouseDragged` function. Then, I can calculate intensities of the image parts inside of the rectangles. The intensities data is in array and this array is used for `NSTableView`. `NSImageView` and `NSTableView` are in the same `NSView`. The intensities calculation is in the `@IBAction` function. After the update when I pressed the button for calculation of the intensities the rectangles moved below the image (before they were staying on top). I have found out, that the reason for this effect is  `reloadData()` function for the table. When this function is turn off the rectangles are staying on top of the image.

Can somebody explain this strange things and what I can do to fix it ? I need to keep the rectangles on top of the image after I pressed the calculation button.

**Update** 
I have updated High Sierra, but `reloadData()` for NSTableView  has the same effect on disappearing the `CAShapeLayers` as before.

Comment: I'm not sure if my answer to my related question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452867/2148757

Comment: I have a related problem, I'm also using nstableview and all my cells become invisible on reloadData() after the highsierra update...

Comment: @user2403221 I have found out (after advice from one guy to set the value for Z axis) when I explicitly set the values for Z axis for the the rectangles (CAShapeLayers), instead of relying on the default values (as it was in Sierra), then CAShapeLayers are staying on top. I guess in Sierra and High Sierra after reloadData() layers are redrawing in different order along Z axis.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem after upgrading to High Sierra, the subviews I was adding to my NSImageView were no longer displayed.

To solve the issue, I added the following line to my code (NSImageView was added programmatically), as recommended by [this link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60023):

```
    imageView.wantsLayer = true
```

Comment: I have looked again in the code, tested what you suggest and found out that now in High Sierra 10.13.4 everything is working as before in Sierra, i.e. without imageView.wantsLayer = true or without writing the values for Z positions of the layers. Probably, some changes were made in High Sierra 10.13.4 in comparison with earlier version of High Sierra.